# How do I check what is killing a process?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-11, process

I have problem with chrome. It works only when main executable is renamed. It appears that something is killing it but I cannot find it. I tried WinApiOverride with no results (TerminateProcess or ExitProcess does not seem to be called). I cannot use LogNT32 becouse chrome is 64 bit application (and I do not think chrome is killing itself). How should I check what is killing chrome.

Comment: have you checked the event log? Have you tried Microsoft Chrome (i.e. Edge)?

Comment: edge and firefox works it is only not renamed chrome. Tryed looking in event viewer. It does not contain any chrome events.

Comment: Does it get closed after a few minutes? Is the machine on a domain?

Comment: I forgot to suggest to rename edge to chrome.exe :p

Comment: I just renamed chrome to chrome1. Works well enouch apart of few things like opening links from email.

Comment: It closes in less then a second. Machine is not on a domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://learn.microsoft.com/sysinternals/downloads/procmon
There is a detailed information about all the process.